# Clean URL in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a partial web page called home.html. When I run the page in chrome, the address shows me http://127.0.0.1:63342/Angular-01/htmlPage1.html?_ijt=vfdcblvb6ahn0t6et7rv6k8tm0#/home where as I should see a cleaner url (without the extension). I have configured my route as:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myModule", ["ngRoute"])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/home", {
                templateUrl: "views/home.html",
                controller: "homeController"
            })
    })
    .controller("homeController", function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Home page";
    })
```

How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

When using angular routing you don't need to call a static page as you are doing home.html. you simply run your app and say you want to go home and angular routing will take you to home.html

> When I run the page in chrome?
>   If you open only a static html page in browser it will serve you only that page not the angular application

### In order to run whole angular app

If you are running your app with http-server or any other node server you need to server the whole angular app and then index.html will be loaded which will load your angular app and your config function will be invoked and it will look for the request and will give you the view

> Note:- you need to put `<div ng-view></div>` for routing

Comment: "When using angular routing you don't need to call a static page as you are doing home.html. you simply run your app and say you want to go home and angular routing will take you to home.html" - how would I change my JS?

Comment: Your js seems to look fine to me.  How are you running your app?